# How do I use a command button to push a record from one table to another

Tags: ms-access

I am currently combining a number of Db applications into one “Enterprise” system for the hospitality industry. This, of course, starts with the point of prime entry which, in this case is EPOS.

I have a form on which I have placed a tab control. Each page represents a drinks group: eg bottled  beers, draught Beers, wines, spirits and so on…
On each page are a number of command buttons each of which “Should” correspond to a product in the table of products.

My question to you all is how do I do it?  Apart from hard coding 400 plus click events?

One would think that it would be possible to  write one single expression to which all buttons could refer with a variable that captured the name (or tag) of the active control but, try as I indeed have, Access simply will not let me do it!

Comment: I would suggest that this will be very difficult to "future-proof" in Access, as you will need to deal with "ProductA" being deleted, "ProductZ" being introduced, and so on. You will very rapidly spend most of your time adding buttons and altering code to deal with this. Ideally you would want a framework that allows you to read from a table and create controls "on the fly".

Comment: Form is limited to 754 controls and sections, deleted controls are included in that count. So if there is a lot of creating and deleting over time, at some point will have to rebuild form - copy all existing controls to a new form. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can have a VBA custom function that can be called in click event property. Example:

```
Private Function HandleButtonClick(intButton As Integer)

Dim strLabNum As String

strLabNum = Nz(Me.ctrSampleList!LABNUM, "")
Me.tbxLABNUM.SetFocus

Select Case intButton
    Case 1 'Login sample
        strLabNum = NewSample
        Me.tbxLABNUM = strLabNum
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Sample", acNormal, , "LabNum='" & strLabNum & "'", , , strLabNum & "," & "Login"
    Case 2 'Transfer sample data
        strLabNum = NewSample
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Transfer", acNormal, , "LabNum='" & strLabNum & "'"
...
End Select
End Function
```

Calling function in event property: `=HandleButtonClick(1)`

Perhaps in your case argument should just be product ID and function saves that ID to field.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid responses people, this is remarkable! Thanks to Applecore for the heads up on control constraints and  to June7 for the code snippet.